# Request in Postman with same cookies and headers like in browser returns 401, but in browser all works fine

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, cookies, postman, http-status-code-401

I trying to scraping data from this url:
https://rgis.mosreg.ru/v3/swagger/map/layer?SERVICE=GeoJSON&layer=34&bbox=37.51027598519073,55.58991,37.84716401480926,55.89414999999997&zoom=11

In web browser, if I visit main page https://rgis.mosreg.ru first (to get cookies), and next - go to this url - all works fine.

But when I trying to perform this request in Postman - its fault with 401 "Unautorized" error.
In Postman I use all same headers and cookies, like in web-browser, but it does not help.
All cookies and headers are synced with browser using Postman INTERCEPTOR

What I missing out?

[Chrome screen with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Y5h.png)
[Postman screen. Header "mojo" looks line auth header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMtl3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server seems to only accept HTTP/2 and reject HTTP/1.1 call. If you have `curl` [compiled with http2 support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884899/how-do-i-install-curl-with-http2-support), you can test this directly:

```
curl --http2 'https://rgis.mosreg.ru/v3/swagger/map/layer?SERVICE=GeoJSON&layer=34&bbox=37.51027598519073,55.58991,37.84716401480926,55.89414999999997&zoom=11'
```

Output

```
< HTTP/2.0 200
< server:nginx/1.19.5 (MOGT Edition @ rgis-pub-app-01)
```

otherwise it returns 401

At the moment, you can't run this request in Postman, because [Postman doesn't have http2 support yet](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2701)

You can also test it with [python](/questions/tagged/python) using the httpx package (`pip install httpx[http2]`):

```py
import httpx
import asyncio

url = 'https://rgis.mosreg.ru/v3/swagger/map/layer?SERVICE=GeoJSON&layer=34&bbox=37.51027598519073,55.58991,37.84716401480926,55.89414999999997&zoom=11'

r = httpx.get(url)
print(r.http_version)
print(r.status_code)

client = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True)


async def get():
    response = await client.get(url)
    print(response.http_version)
    print(response.status_code)

asyncio.run(get())
```

Output

```
HTTP/1.1
401
HTTP/2
200
```